# How to fix typerror dealing with '<='

Tags: python, python-3.x

what the codes is supposed to is take the users input and then movie the rectangle around and when I run the code i get a Typeerror:<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

these were some of the comments made on my code

1. For both Point and Rectangle class constructors, you are providing default values for the parameters. You should not since the assignment states, you should make them required arguments. (-4)
2. rectangleCount static attribute of the Rectangle class not kept up to date (should be incremented in the constructor to keep track of count of Rectangle objects created so far) (-2)
3. Rectangle's constructor doesn't check if width and height is negative, and if so print error message. (-2)
4. Calculations in the bottomRight property is incorrect. (-2) It should be

```
    @property
    def bottomRight(self):
        return Point(self.topLeft.x + self.width, self.topLeft.y + self.height)
```

5. Calculations in the perimeter proper

```
    # Prog 120
    # Rectangle & Point Classes


    class Point:
        def __init__(self, x, y): # makes the value required
            self.__x = x
            self.__y = y

        @property  # read only property for x
        def x(self):
            return self.__x


        @property  # read only property for y
        def y(self):
            return self.__y

        def translate(self, dx, dy):  # moves x coordinate by 'dx' amount of time  and move dy
            self.__x += dx
            self.__y += dy


    class Rectangle:
        DEFAULT_WIDTH = 1 # static attributes
        DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 1
        rectangleCount = 0

        def __init__(self, topLeft, width, height):
            self.__topLeft = topLeft

            # check width argument
            if (width <= 0):
                print("Invalid width")
                self.__width = Rectangle.DEFAULT_WIDTH
            else:
                self.__width = width

             # check height argument
            if (height <= 0):
                 print("Invalid Height")
                 self.__height = Rectangle.DEFAULT_HEIGHT
            else:
                self.__height = height

            Rectangle.rectangleCount +=1 #updates the count of rectangels created


        @property
        def topLeft(self):
            return self.__topLeft

        @topLeft.setter
        def topLeft(self, newTopLeft):
            self.__topLeft = newTopLeft

        @property
        def width(self):
            return self.__width

        @width.setter
        def width(self, newWidth):
            if (newWidth <= 0):
                print("Width cannot be less than '0'. ")
            else:
                self.__width = newWidth

        @property
        def height(self):
            return self.__height

        @height.setter
        def height(self, newHeight):
            if (newHeight <= 0):
                print("Height cannot be less than '0'. ")
            else:
                self.__height = newHeight

        @property
        def bottomRight(self):
            return Point(self.topLeft.x + self.topLeft.y + self.height)

        @property
        def area(self):
            return self.__width * self.__height

        @property
        def perimeter(self):
            return self.__width *2 + self.__height *2 


        def translate(self, dx, dy):  # moves x coordinate by 'dx' amount of time and move y
            self.__topLeft.translare(dx,dy) 

    def main():
        bill = Point(x="", y="")
        will = Rectangle(topLeft="", width="", height="")
        if will.width and will.height < 0:
            print("Width and Height cannot be less than 0.")
            will.width = will.DEFAULT_WIDTH
            will.height = will.DEFAULT_HEIGHT
        will.rectangleCount += 1

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: `will = Rectangle(topLeft="", width="", height="")` Why are you trying to create a rectangle with width and height as empty strings?  That makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
bill = Point(x="", y="")
will = Rectangle(topLeft="", width="", height="")
```

Here you are setting the attributes in `Rectangle` to the empty string.

And here:

```
 def __init__(self, topLeft, width, height):
            self.__topLeft = topLeft

            # check width argument
            if (width <= 0):
                print("Invalid width")
                self.__width = Rectangle.DEFAULT_WIDTH
```

You are comparing that string to `0` - an int. Obviously you can't compare `""` with `0`. That doesn't make any sense. That's what python is telling you with that error message.

Maybe try passing integers to the constructors. Like this:

```
bill = Point(x=5, y=9)
will = Rectangle(topLeft=2, width=4, height=1)
```

Comment: i left it blank becuse its supposed to reveice input from the user but i think i missed that part where i was supposed to have the method that asks for that.

Comment: Either way, you need to pass an `int` or `float` to the constructors, and not a string. Or you can convert the strings into numbers inside the class as well.

Comment: how would I pass the int or float to the constructor so that its required ?

Comment: No sure i understand what you mean by that